# Parsing Information From a File

Tags: java, file, parsing, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read in information from a file in order to create a Graph using Java. I have the code below, however, after running the output is null.

The file gives information similar to below

> 3
>
> Kentucky Florida Alabama
>
> ...
>
> ...

Where 3 is the amount of vertices in the graph, and the 3 locations in the following line are those vertices. I'm struggling to figure out what's resulting in a null output.

```
public class ReadGraph {
  static int vertNum = 0;
  static String[] output;

  public static String[] readVertices(Scanner fileIn) throws FileNotFoundException {
    fileIn = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    vertNum = fileIn.nextInt();
    output = new String[vertNum];
    for (int i = 0; i < vertNum - 1; i++) {
        output[i] = fileIn.next();
    }
    Arrays.sort(output);
    fileIn.close();
    return output;
   }
}
```

output should be a list of the locations in alphabetical order at this point. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do a step by step debugging and find which line doesn't do what you think it should do.

Comment: Why does your method `readVertices()` take a `Scanner` as parameter, but then creates a `new Scanner()` right away?

Comment: the `for (int i = 0; i < vertNum - 1; i++)` should be `for(int i=0 ; i<vertNum ; i++)`

Comment: @domdom Because I wasn't sure how to get it to read from a file without creating a new Scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `fileIn` object reads the first line, it found the number `3`, with this value you are initializing the `output` array, in the loop you are subtracting one (`vertNum - 1`), so when the `Arrays` try to sort, it does not found the complete array, there are just 2 elements so it throws an exception. To avoid this exception you shouldn't subtract one element in the loop, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertNum; i++) {
    output[i] = fileIn.next();
}
```

**Update:**
Complete example:

```
public class ReadGraph {
    static int vertNum = 0;
    static String[] output;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner fileIn = null;
        for (String s : readVertices(fileIn)) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static String[] readVertices(Scanner fileIn) throws FileNotFoundException {
        fileIn = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        vertNum = fileIn.nextInt();
        output = new String[vertNum];
        for (int i = 0; i < vertNum; i++) {
            output[i] = fileIn.next();
        }
        Arrays.sort(output);
        fileIn.close();
        return output;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Alabama
Florida
Kentucky
```

Comment: This does not resolve the issue. The output array still results in null.